# How to adjust head, tail pointers when building a LinkedList

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, memory-address

I am making a simple implementation of LinkedList. My Trial:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode* next;
    int val;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

int main()
{
    ListNode* head = NULL;
    ListNode* tail;
    int data;
    cout<<"Enter data. Enter -1 to terminate insertion"<<endl;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>data;
        if(data != -1)
        {
            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = new ListNode(data); // Returns the address of a new ListNode and stores it in head
                tail = head->next; // tail now points to head's next
            }
            else
            {
                tail = new ListNode(data); // address of a new ListNode is in tail
                tail = tail->next; // Tail now points to the new ListNode's next
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    tail = NULL; // Tail ends with a NULL
    while(head)
    {
        cout<<head->val<<" ";
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

When I input 1, 2, 3: I expect the Linked List to be formed as `1->2->3->NULL`.

However, the Linked List is always only the first element `1->NULL`

I ran on the debugger and indeed, `head->next` is always `NULL`. But I dont understand why. I am specifically changing head's next to a new ListNode non-null address when I do `tail = new ListNode(data)`, but apparently thats not happening. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code: http://cpp.sh/6ardx

Comment: You clearly never modify `head->next` to point at next node.

Comment: @VTT, I am doing it, `tail = head->next` and in the else `tail = new ListNode(data)`. Please correct my logic incase if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Those statements actually modify `tail` variable, but leave `head->next` unchanged.

Comment: @VTT Oh, My understanding is that since I am working with pointers, the changes that I make are reflected at the address too. How do I correct this?

Comment: `tail = head->next` only copies an address currently stored in `head->next` variable into `tail` variable, nothing else. You need to modify `head->next` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: `tail` is always NULL. 
How do you want to make the connection between `tail` and appended node to your list when `tail` is NULL ?

When list is empty and you create the first node, after inserting first node `head` and `tail` should point to the same node. Change

```
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = new ListNode(data); // Returns the address of a new ListNode and stores it in head
            tail = head->next; // tail now points to head's next
        }
```

to

```
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            tail = head = new ListNode(data); // Returns the address of a new ListNode and stores it in head
        }
```

the second issue, when you add to the end of list you should update `tail->next` to point to the inserted node, so change

```
        tail = new ListNode(data); // address of a new ListNode is in tail
        tail = tail->next; // Tail now points to the new ListNode's next
```

to

```
        tail->next  = new ListNode(data); // address of a new ListNode is in tail
        tail = tail->next; // Tail now points to the new ListNode's next
```